# How to Capture a pcap trace when both the server and client are in the same machine?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, wireshark, tshark

I have a SMPP server and client are running on different ports in the same machine, and i would like to capture the pcap to see the smpp messages.
Because of the same machine, it was not captured in tshark command.

Is there any option to capture the messages if both client and server on the same machine?

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of UN*X support capturing on the "loopback" interface, which is the interface on which the traffic between the server and the client will appear.  (Alpesh Gediya is mistaken here; the traffic may not be queued up for an actual network interface controller, but it *is* queued up for the loopback interface.)  Others don't.

Try running `tshark -D` the same way you ran tshark when you tried capturing traffic; if it reports an interface with a name such as `lo` (Linux) or `lo0` (*BSD, OS X, some other UN*Xes), try capturing on that interface.  If it doesn't report such an interface, you're running on a UN*X that doesn't support capturing on the loopback interface, such as Solaris 10 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

While you have server and Clinet on same machine , Data packets are not put in NIC queue by Operating System due to this reason you can not capture packets on same machine.

You can use TCPMON utility to capture packates by routing it.

Comment: TCPMON also availible for Unix as well.

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you keep CLIENT and server of SMPP on one machine any specific reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Note you can capture on multiple interfaces at the same time with tshark, by using the `-i` option multiple times. So one way to go about this is to take all the interfaces from the output of `tshark -D` and put all of these interfaces in your tshark command-line like this:

```
tshark -i <iface0> -i <iface1> -i <iface2> ... <other options>
```

If you listed all interfaces and didn't find the traffic you wanted then tshark is likely not able to capture it.